# Admin is blank after product import, frontend still working

Tags: product, import

I did a product import and the admin side of the website is no longer working. I can see the top nav menu but that's it. The front end is also working so I'm guessing the database is not affected.

Any idea on what I could try to do?

FYI, I did cleared /var/cache & var/session folders without any luck.

[image]

Comment: do you see your site content in the source code or is that also blank?

Comment: The source content stops after the menu.

Comment: this is the end 

</li>
</ul>
<!-- menu end -->

    <a id="page-help-link" href="http://www.magentocommerce.com/gethelp/en_US/Mage_Adminhtml/dashboard/index/">Get help for this page</a>
    <script type="text/javascript">$('page-help-link').target = 'magento_page_help'</script>

</div>
        </div>

Comment: I have no idea then.. if you still had content in the source then it could have been a css/js issue but now I don't know.. you can't get to any page from the menu? or just the dashboard isn't loading?

Comment: nop, I can't go no where. 

it might be the apache apc, I waiting for a AWS team to disable it.

I'll update in a few hours.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by the [Alternative PHP Cache](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php).

As soon as this was disabled everything was working after.